# How to generate random value between 0-5

Tags: xpath, robotframework

If I use  Generate Random string, Its not giving between the selected range.

```
${child node click value}=  Generate Random String  1   [NUMBERS]${convetingto number}
```

If ${convetingto number} = 4

It should generate  till  Random Number 4 . It should not go beyond it..But Its generating till 9.

Comment: just create a random value and then use modular 5 :)

Comment: please try to format you source code properly

Comment: This is not valid robotframework code.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize you wanted to give maximum value for Generate Random. You should just use Python's random library directly:

```
*** Settings ***
Library         random

*** Test Cases ***

Stackoverflow
    ${converting to number}=        Set Variable    4
    ${min value}=                   Convert to Integer    0
    ${converting to number}=        Convert to Integer    ${converting to number}
    ${child node click value}=      random.randint    ${min value}    ${converting to number}
```

Comment: {convetingto number}  can have any values 0-9. but when it has values till 4. random numbers should be within it.

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
${child node click value}=  Generate Random String  1   [NUMBERS]${convetingto number}
```

*${child node click value}* will get a letter in range 0-9 OR a letter appears in string value of *${convetingto number}*.

Example: if ${conveting to number} is abcdef, the return value can be one of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f.

To solve your problem, I think you can use this code:

```
${text}          Set Variable              0
:FOR             ${index}                  IN RANGE        1        ${converting to number}+1
\                ${text}                   Set Variable    ${text}${index}
${child node}    Generate Random String    1               ${text}
```